# Como hacer crear un stash con los cambios que estan en el stage area

Tags: git

Actualmente tengo muchos cambios pero quiero guarda de manera provisional algunos 
que están en una carpeta especifica.

Quisiera saber alguna forma guardar esos cambios de manera especifica.

algo como git stash save rutaDeArchivos

Comment: Con stash según tengo entendido me parece que no, de todas formas la documentación oficial de éste está en [git-stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) aunque creo que obtendrías un buen resultado utilizando ramas en lugar de solo almacenar algunos cambios con `stash`

Answer (score 2):

Para conseguir lo que buscas debes añadir al stage los cambios que deseas almacenar en stash.

```
git add archivos_para_stash
```

Una vez hecho esto, con la opción ***--keep-index*** , conseguiremos que añada al stash todo lo demás.

```
git stash --keep-index
```

De esta manera te quedarás solamente con los cambios que deseas añadir al stash. Ahora simplemente añade esos cambios a otro stash con algún nombre que te resulte útil.

```
git stash save "Cambios útiles para stash"
```

Finalmente recupera el primer stash creado con la opción ***--keep-index***, y te quedarás con los cambios restantes que no querías añadir al stash. Espero que te sirva.

Referencias:
[Stashing only staged changes in git - is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759748/stashing-only-staged-changes-in-git-is-it-possible)